# Get email address from registration form

Tags: craft3

I have a user registration form setup to redirect to another template on submit. That template then includes the following:

```
{% set email = craft.app.request.getBodyParam('email') -%}
<p>Thank you for registering. An email has been sent to {{ email }}…
```

Why does `getBodyParam('email')` always return empty here? `getBodyParams()` also returns an empty array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does getBodyParam('email') always return empty here?

Because that method is looking for data in POST, and after the redirect has happened, it's a new request, and POST data is lost.

If you want to do what you're looking for, the easiest way is to pass the email address along as a query string param (i.e. `?email=foo@bar.com`), then the template can do `craft.app.request.getQueryParam('email')`.

Comment: Thanks Brad. Is that possible with just twig and the standard registration form, or are you thinking JS or a plugin to capture the email value?